# GOLang Game of Life Implementation

Tags: go, game-of-life

I decided to give Go a try and implemented a Game of Life Kata exercise in GOLang. I have no prior experience in Go and the majority of my experience comes from Java, C#, and Python. My code appears to be working as intended but not sure if I've implemented it in the GO way, or idiomatic Go.

I've seen a few Go examples online where the properties of the struct were always public, but that feels foreign coming from the object-orient world. The way I've implemented it the Board struct should never be able to get into an invalid state. I don't know if that is a mindset that is shared by the Go community.

I have a colleague who is big into Go and favors immutability and no side effects. I can see how that would be ideal for concurrency, but does the general Go community prefer avoiding mutations? As an example I could have implemented my Evolve method to return a new Board struct rather than mutate its state property.

Is there anything else that stands out as not being Go like?

```
package board

import (
    "errors"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const CellDead = 0
const CellAlive = 1

type board struct {
    state [][]int
    rows int
    columns int
}

/* Creates a new Board with the given dimensions. The dimensions, rows and columns,
must be positive integers greater than 0.
Returns a board populated with a random state. */
func NewRandomBoard(rows, columns int) (board, error) {

    if rows < 1 || columns < 1 {
        return board{}, errors.New("rows and columns must be a positive integer greater than 0")
    }

    initState := make([][]int, rows)
    for i := range initState {
        initState[i] = make([]int, columns)
    }

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    // Populate random state
    for i := range initState {
        for j := range initState[i] {
            initState[i][j] = rand.Intn((1 -0 + 1) + 0)
        }
    }

    return board{state: initState, rows:rows, columns:columns}, nil
}

func NewBoard(initialState [][]int) (board, error) {

    if initialState == nil {
        return board{}, errors.New("initialState cannot be nil")
    }

    if len(initialState) < 1 || len(initialState[0]) < 1 {
        return board{}, errors.New("initialState must contain at least 1 row and 1 column")
    }

    colSize := len(initialState[0])
    for i := 0; i < len(initialState); i++ {
        if colSize != len(initialState[i]) {
            return board{}, errors.New("initialState is a jagged 2D array, initialState cannot be jagged")
        }
        for j := 0; j < len(initialState[i]); j++ {
            cellValue := initialState[i][j]
            if cellValue < 0 || cellValue > 1 {
                return board{}, errors.New("initialState may only contain values 0 or 1")
            }
        }
    }

    return board{state:initialState, rows: len(initialState), columns: len(initialState[0])}, nil
}

func (b *board) Evolve() {
    newState := make([][]int, b.rows)
    for i := range newState {
        newState[i] = make([]int, b.columns)
        for j := range newState[i] {
            newState[i][j] = nextStateForCell(b,i,j)
        }
    }
    b.state = newState
}

func (b *board) State() [][]int {
    return b.state
}

func (b *board) Rows() int {
    return b.rows
}

func (b *board) Columns() int {
    return b.columns
}

func (b *board) PrettyPrint() {
    for i := range b.state {
        for j := range b.state[i] {
            print(" " + strconv.Itoa(b.state[i][j]) + "")
        }
        println()
    }
}

func nextStateForCell(b *board, i,j int) int {

    neighborsAlive := 0
    cellValue := b.state[i][j]
    for x := -1; x <= 1; x++ {
        for y := -1; y <= 1; y++ {
            if i + x < 0 || i + x > (b.rows - 1) || y + j < 0 || y + j > (b.columns - 1) {
                continue
            }
            neighborsAlive += b.state[i + x][y + j]
        }
    }
    neighborsAlive -= cellValue

    if cellValue == CellDead && neighborsAlive == 3 {
        return CellAlive
    } else if cellValue == CellAlive && (neighborsAlive < 2 || neighborsAlive > 3) {
        return CellDead
    } else {
        return cellValue
    }
}
```

The main file

```
package main

import (
    "io.jkratz/katas/life/board"
)

func main() {

    myBoard, err := board.NewRandomBoard(10, 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to instantiate board")
    }

    myBoard.PrettyPrint()
    println()
    myBoard.Evolve()
    myBoard.PrettyPrint()
}
```

Comment: package is called `board`, and there's a function called `NewBoard`. The call stutters. Writing `board.New()` communicates the exact same thing as `board.NewBoard()` without the repetition. check [the golang code review](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) wiki for more conventions that are widely adopted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything else that stands out as not being Go like?

While reading through your code, I only noticed a few things that weren't idiomatic Go, so congrats!

### Avoid `print()` and `println()` in favor of `fmt`

```
for i := range b.state {
    for j := range b.state[i] {
        print(" " + strconv.Itoa(b.state[i][j]) + "")
    }
    println()
}
```

Becomes:

```
for i := range b.state {
    for j := range b.state[i] {
        fmt.Printf(" %d ", b.state[i][j])
    }

    fmt.Println()
}
```

Notice that you also avoid `strconv.Itoa()`.

### `rand.Intn((1 -0 + 1) + 0)`

You mean `rand.Intn(2)`?

### `log.Fatal()` instead of `panic()`

In your example usage, you use `panic()` to raise an error. Unless you plan to `recover()` from that, you can use `log.Fatal()` to write to standard error and exit the program.

```
panic("Failed to instantiate board")
```

Would be more commonly done as:

```
log.Fatalf("Failed to instantiate board: %s", err)
```

Or whatever error grammar you prefer. If you have an error value, you might as well use it to indicate the potential problem to the user.

### Inconsistent formatting

For example:

```
func nextStateForCell(b *board, i,j int) int {
```

Would be consistently spaced as such:

```
func nextStateForCell(b *board, i, j int) int {
```

It's a nitpick. If you run `go fmt` on the source code, it should fix these kinds of things. If you use vim, there's also [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), which I find very helpful.

---

> I have a colleague who is big into Go and favors immutability and no side effects. I can see how that would be ideal for concurrency, but does the general Go community prefer avoiding mutations?

I'm not sure if there's a consensus. Normally the answer is: "It depends." I think the way you've done it is fine. By mutating the state directly, you avoid potentially-costly memory allocations. So, for example, if you want to see the state after a trillion generations, it would likely be faster than if you constantly reassign based on return values.

Since you're new to Go, I recommend experimenting with concurrency. Here, you can concurrently read and determine the next state of the board.

---

[Here](https://golang.org/doc/play/life.go) is another example of a Go implementation of Conway's Game of Life, straight from the Go website.

Notice that they use a boolean field, rather than an integer one. This is more common (and performant), given that living is boolean.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times, thanks for the thorough answer and explanation!